# ionic serve error: unknown option `--address'

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, serve

I keep getting this error whenever I do an ionic serve. I've looked through so many posts and tried quite a few suggestions, but it still doesn't seem to accept any parms.

The command it seems to be generating is:

> npm run ionic:serve -- --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser

and the output is:

[npm] > node ./bin/pp envs generate local ; node_modules/.bin/ionic-app-scripts serve "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729" "--dev-logger-port" "53703" "--nobrowser"
[npm]   error: unknown option `--address'

I've tried running the generated command directly with each of the parms separately, but it doesn't recognise any of them.

I'm on ionic 4.1.1, but it happened with previous 4x versions too.

Any ideas as to how to solve this would be gratefully received.

Comment: Do you have a firewall on your local ? Proxy ?

Comment: No. no proxy and the firewall is no problem.